# Running executeBatch() from another location

Tags: java, mysql

I want to create another method called public void execute() and run the preparedStmt.executeBatch(); from there, but I don't know how.

```
   public void save() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Sacuvano nov proizvod sa sifrom: " + proizvodID + " Naziv proizvoda: " + naziv));
        try {
            String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/fpis";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "root");

            String query = " insert into proizvod values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, proizvodID);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, naziv);
            preparedStmt.setString(3, opis);
            preparedStmt.setDouble(4, cena);
            preparedStmt.setString(5, jedMere);
            preparedStmt.addBatch();

            preparedStmt.executeBatch();

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Greska!");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
     public void execute(){
        {
```

Comment: Why? What is the point? What's wrong with the way you're doing it now? If you transfer the whole thing to another method you also have to transfer the `Connection`, so it can be closed, and arguably the `PreparedStatement`, ditto.

Comment: I wanted to create a batch with all inserts in order to send all inserts to database at once after calling a method. I thought that if I ran executeBatch() from a different location, .addBatch() would save all my data in preparedStmt, but sadly that's not the case.

Comment: It *is* the case. What are you talking about? What is the underlying problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare `PreparedStatement preparedStmt` and `Connection conn` as a attribute of your class.
Like that you could setup `preparedStmt` in `public void save()` and `conn` in your constructor. After that, just call `preparedStmt.executeBatch();` from `public void execute();` and close `conn` after.

Comment: That solved my problem, no idea who gave you that -. Appreciate your help.